# SD card available memory loss after formatting with Ubuntu

Tags: sd-card

I purchased a new SanDisk 32Gb micro SD card and formatted it using Raspberry Pi imager on a Windows 10 machine. All went fine however I realised I should have included OS customisation. When trying to redo again using Raspberry Pi imager to reformat, etc, I thought I had succeeded howvever install failed. Find now that the card only has 3.6Gb of memory available. How do I get back to my original 32Gb?

Comment: This should be easy. Put the card in your computer. Due to the size the manufacturer has chosen EXFAT as format of the main partition, may be  FAT32. If you accidentially chose FAT16 or FAT8 it can not address all memory due to the small index size. If you prefer  GUI tools just take gparted to format the card and use exfat. On the CLI just use mkfs.exfat. You may chose some options. You always have the choice to use NTFS as well. If your devices like it. Some don't.  By far the fastest read-write is achieved by using exfat format (always applies for all USB thumbsticks).  What you think?

Comment: If the problem persists after putting a new partition and formatting it, take a look at the f3 package (fight fake flash).

Answer (score 0):

Install and open Gparted in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

Choose the drive belonging to the microsd card on the upper right corner (could be `/dev/mmcblkX` where X is a number).

Delete all the partitions, and create a new FAT32 partition with all the space.

Comment: I tried installing gparted on my Windows 10 PC (where the SD card was being read using card reader) in order to remove the extra partitions that had beed added (which reduced the "available" memory fron 32Gb to 3.6Gb. However its seems now that one has to take out a yearly subscription to use it. With regard to your suggestion of installing Gparted in Ubuntu, I'm not sure how this works as the partition problem is the one that stops me from loading Ubuntu. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: We don't support Windows on this site.

Comment: You can also use the gparted live image instead of ubuntu https://gparted.org/download.php